# Visual Basic Text Box Array for random number generator - For Homework

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers

I'm wanting to make a random number generator. It's for school homework. I just can't seem to get it to work.

The task was to make a random number generator to generate 20 numbers into 20 text boxes to ask 10 maths questions.

It needs to be as efficient as possible. I need help as I can only do it but it's really inefficient and really long code.

```
Dim RandomNumberAHigh As Integer = 12 'Here I am declaring my highest number for the random number generator to use. This will be the highest number the maths quiz will ask the students in the questions.
Dim RandomNumberALow As Integer = 1 'Here I am declaring my lowest number for the random number generator to use. This will be the lowest number the maths quiz will ask the students in the questions.
Dim Random As Integer = 0 'Her I am declaring a variable that will be used to insert the numbers from the random number generator in the quiz text boxes.
Randomize()
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd1.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd4.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd7.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd10.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd13.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd16.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd19.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd22.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd25.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd28.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd3.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd6.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd9.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd12.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd15.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd18.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd21.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd24.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd27.Text = (Random)
Random = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
Rnd30.Text = (Random)
```

Comment: What is your specific need?

Comment: Exact duplicate of: [Visual Basic Text Box Array for random number generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005056/visual-basic-text-box-array-for-random-number-generator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Efficient" is pretty subjective.  There are **many** ways to do it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RandomizeTextBoxes(1, 12)
End Sub

Private Sub RandomizeTextBoxes(ByVal Low As Integer, ByVal High As Integer)
    Static R As New Random
    For i As Integer = 1 To 30
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("Rnd" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
            DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox).Text = R.Next(Low, High + 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Idle_Mind's answer, this uses the Textbox's Name property to determine whether it should have the Text Property assigned a generated value.

The difference here is I am enumerating through the control collection; using IEnumerable in a For Each loop. In this manner, I don't have to check through the control collection, against the length of the control collection, or cast the control within the processing of the loop.

```
Sub RandomizeTextBoxes(min As Integer, max As Integer)
    Dim r As Random = New Random()
    Dim RandomTextboxes As IEnumerable(Of TextBox) = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(AddressOf DoesTextboxNameContainRnd)
    For Each tbControl As TextBox In RandomTextboxes
        tbControl.Text = r.Next(min, max)
    Next
End Sub

Function DoesTextboxNameContainRnd(tbControl As TextBox) As Boolean
    Return tbControl.Name.Contains("Rnd")
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RandomizeTextBoxes(1, 50)
End Sub
```

Comment: By passing the addressof `DoesTextboxNameContainRnd` function to the collection (by virtue of the where method), I'm passing a predictate function that will be tested against each object in the collection, and the resulting new collection of the objects that returned true in that predicate.  This style of programming is referred to as contra-varient programming.